# How to change textView in separate ViewController from button in another ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button, uiviewcontroller

I have a Collections View that includes various cells that are also buttons. Upon clicking one of those buttons, a separate ViewController is shown (I just connected the button to the ViewController and clicked "show"). I would like to know how to switch the textView in that separate ViewController for every different button in my Collections View.

Here's the code in my CollectionsView:

```
class Example : UICollectionViewController {

var Array = [String]()

var ButtonArray = [String]()

@IBOutlet var menu: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    Array = ["A", "B", "C, "D]

    ButtonArray = ["", "", "", ""]

    menu.target = self.revealViewController()
    menu.action = Selector("revealToggle:")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

    var Label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

    Label.text = Array[indexPath.row]

    var Button = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton

    Button.setTitle(ButtonArray[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    return cell
}  
}
```

And the code in the separate ViewController:

```
class Example2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var exText: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps...

1: Create a Separate file called Manager.swift and place this code in it...

```
//manager.swift

    import Foundation

    struct Manager {

    static var messageText = [String]()


    }
```

2: Clean your project by pressing Shift+Command+K.

3: In the first view controller set the messageText to the text fields text...

```
Manager.messageText.append(self.textField.text)
```

4: In the second view controller retrieve the text and set the label to the message text...

```
self.label.text = Manager.messageText[0]
```

5: Your Finished!!

Comment: Hey thanks! That worked. How can I can set it so that each button presents different text (rather than all say the same thing) in the separate ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

That was one way, and it relies on creating a global variable that can be defined out of the scope of any available class, no new file needed here. Just define the variable above (or below) the class code.
Another good way is to use UserDefaults that are automatically saved in app settings file, this way the variable is retained, and when you restart the app again the value will be the same you left with.
Swift 3+

```
To store/change a value:

    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(yourValue, forKey: "yourKey")

To retrieve a value

    UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "yourKey")
```